# Ionic 3 remote content loading issue on safari 10

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ecmascript-6, ionic3

We are trying to load the webapp content inside ionic 3 Mobile Application and
It is working fine on IOS 11 & 12 also on android

But on IOS 10.2 it is not loading and when we do remote debugging.We can see couple of issues in the browser (App works well when we do not load content remotely)
1) viewport argument key "viewport-fit" not recognized
2) cannot declare a let variable twice

Can anyone tell us how can we solve these ?

Comment: check this link https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1637#issuecomment-322317297

Comment: and this one also https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to handle this.

This can be resolved using below changes the script

create file uglifyjs.config.js & set safari 10 mangle option to true -

```
let defaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/uglifyjs.config');

module.exports = Object.assign({}, defaultConfig, {
    mangle: Object.assign({}, defaultConfig.mangle, {
        safari10: true
    })
});
```

Use it inside package.json under config

```
 "config": {
    ......
    "ionic_uglifyjs": "./uglifyjs.config.js"
  },
```